# Matplotlib: TexLive installation does not work

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, pdflatex

I am trying to use Latex in my plots. However, if I use
`plt.rc('text', usetex=True)`, I get the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 277, in _run_checked_subprocess
   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
   **kwargs).stdout

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
   output=stdout, stderr=stderr)

CalledProcessError: Command '['latex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '--halt-on-error', 'C:\\Users\\Leo\\.matplotlib\\tex.cache\\d97ff769cca1b07656427b11e7187cec.tex']' returned non-zero exit status 1.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py", line 341, in __call__
   return printer(obj)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 248, in <lambda>
   png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 132, in print_figure
   fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2193, in print_figure
   self.figure.draw(renderer)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
   return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1864, in draw
   renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
   a.draw(renderer)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
   return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 411, in wrapper
   return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2747, in draw
   mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
   a.draw(renderer)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
   return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1166, in draw
   renderer)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1092, in _get_tick_bboxes
   for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1092, in <listcomp>
   for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 900, in get_window_extent
   bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 287, in _get_layout
   ismath="TeX" if self.get_usetex() else False)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 228, in get_text_width_height_descent
   s, fontsize, renderer=self)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 423, in get_text_width_height_descent
   dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 311, in make_dvi
   texfile], tex)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 290, in _run_checked_subprocess
   exc=exc.output.decode('utf-8'))) from exc

RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'lp'

Here is the full report generated by latex:
failed to create process.
```

I have installed TexLive and can call it from the commmand prompt by typing latex. It is located in the folder
`C:\texlive`

I have previously installed MikTex and been trying to solve this for hours now, please help me!

Comment: yes, I get `pdfTex 3.14.. (Tex Live 2020)`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from a (working) `LaTeX` installation, you also need `dvipng` (you could check if it is included in your TexLive distribution, otherwise download it) and `Ghostscript` (version 9.0 or later). The binaries for *all* of these three components need to be located on your `PATH` variable. Since you indicate that you can call `latex` from the prompt, this one seems to be in your `PATH` already.

I would advice you to check if you have (1) the proper `dvipng` and `Ghostscript` binaries on your system and (2) if they are located on your `PATH`.

If none of this helps, you could have a look at the [matplotlib usetex documentation page](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/text/usetex.html). Near the bottom of the page, you can find two sections ('Possible hangups' and 'Troubleshooting') which might help you out further.